# Swift: Most efficient way to place an entire array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm placing all 4 items from an array `graphics`, then moving three of them.

Besides a for loop, is there a shorter way to place the entire array `graphics` at the same position? i.e. How do I place an entire array at a single point?

```
// Position a graphic in each quadrant.
for i in 0 ... 3 {
    scene.place(graphics[i], at: Point(x: x, y: y))
}
graphics[1].move(to: Point(x: x, y: -y), duration: 2)
graphics[2].move(to: Point(x: -x, y: -y), duration: 2)
graphics[3].move(to: Point(x: -x, y: y), duration: 2)
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your `for` loop?

Comment: You will have to do a `for loop` or you could do `graphics.forEach{}`


`for i in 0 ... 3 {` doing this is very bad if you do 

`graphics.forEach{scene.place($0, at: Point(x: x, y: y))}`, you won't have to worry about the count or length of your array.

Comment: @m_callens  
Curious if there's a method for arrays so I can do it in 1 line instead of 3?

Leif has a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `graphics.forEach{ scene.place($0, at: Point(x: x, y: y)) }`

Comment: Works, thanks! I'd vote it up but my account is too new  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯